# Cypher query returning specific attributes of distinct nodes type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is the data model I use for modeling production and sale of art works:

[image: Data model]

This includes unit label (original or master copy) and edition label (reproduction). Both are available to sale. Unit and Edition nodes have distinct attributes.

I did not manage to write a cypher query (used trough neo4j CE edtion browser) in order to produce a table of unit and edition sales returning specific attributes of both Unit and Edition nodes.

Do you see a solution for that?

Here are some requested details : [nodes attributes expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejhfj.jpg)

Comment: This seems very vague. Can you add more detail on what attributes you want returned (and which attributes are shared by each vs specific to Unit or Edition)? Also, what have you tried so far, and how has that attempt not met what you want?

Comment: If your query returns both :Unit and :Edition nodes, and if you want all attributes whether it's one or the other, just return the node (or `properties(n)`). The attributes will be included.

Comment: What are unit and edition? Do you want to match the sale to unit and edition?

Comment: An Edition is a reproduction (usually in a different material) of a Unit. A Unit is unique. There may be few Edition of a Unit. The query should return all the sales (both Unit and Edition) with specific attributes to Unit or Edition and Edition attributes herited from the original (Unit). See also the requested details added in the post.